# Increase video resolution but not visible size

Tags: html, css, flash, video

I do understand this is a pretty dumb question just wondering how this would be achieved, Basically I'm trying to get the best possible resolution from this webcam script and the trouble I'm having is when I set the resolution to `1920 x 1080` it obviously changes the size of the webcam broadcast plugin, What I want to achieve is broadcast the webcam at `1080p` but have the player scaled to `320x240`. so the height and width of the actual webcam box is `320x240` but the script is broadcasting the webcam at `1080p`?

```
<embed  src="/_broadcast/webcam.swf"
               flashvars="rtmp address"
               bgcolor="#ffffff"
               width="1920"
               height="1080"
               quality="high"
               allowScriptAccess="always"
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

I really do appologise for the poorness of this question just couldn't find much online regarding this issue. Thankyou in advance.

> I did try adding it to a div with a set width and height however this
>   did not resolve the issue.

Comment: In the HTML code just use : `width="320"` and `height="240"`. Those numbers are the SWF display size in webpage. They should not affect the broadcast video resolution (unless there's something we need to know about this script?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1080p refers to how the images are saved when recorded by a webcam. It is 1920 pixels wide and 1080 pixels high. Your source video will always be 1080p if that is what the webcam records in src="/_broadcast/webcam.swf". You can convert the video to lower resolution if you want by running through a separate program such as ffmpeg. You can alternatively convert to a lower resolution using html canvas. Obviously if somebody has a small screen like a phone you wouldn't need high resolution and it would take ages for the phone to load it so therefore the major video sites convert videos to multiple resolutions.

Comment: As a side note most high end videos require graphics cards to work. Phones aren't capable of even running high resolution videos. It doesn't have anything to do with internet connection.